# JTable row color change based on a column value- on pop up click

Tags: swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecellrenderer

My `jTable` is loaded with data and this is where I call my Pop up functionality on `jTable`.

```
jTable.addMouseListener(new TablePopupListener(jTable));
displayTable();
```

So basically, if I right-click a row, a popup(credit check) comes up and if I click it is setting a value to the last cell in that row. Now, based on this column cell value I have to define the color of a row. Let's say if the cell value fails then turn the row to red else to green. I have tried `customCellRenderer` and defined my condition but there is no change in row color. The custom cell renderer worked great for a button functionality that I had to write, though. The below code uses prepare `cellRenderer` which I felt is easy but I don't see any change in row color.

I am missing some connection, plz provide me help.

Thanks in advance.

```
    class TablePopupListener extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener { 
        JPopupMenu popup; 
        JTable table; 
        int[] selRows; 
        TableModel model; 
        ArrayList rowValueList = new ArrayList(); 
        JMenuItem creditCheck = new JMenuItem("Credit Check");

        public TablePopupListener(JTable jTable) {
            this.table = jTable;
            model = table.getModel();
            popup = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem creditCheck = new JMenuItem("Credit Check");
            creditCheck.addActionListener(this);
            popup.add(creditCheck);

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
           firePopup(me);
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
           firePopup(me);
        }

        public void firePopup(MouseEvent me) {

            /*
             * The popup menu will be shown only if there is a row selection in the
             * table
             */

            // popup.show(table, me.getX(), me.getY());
            if (me.isPopupTrigger() && table.getModel().getRowCount() != 0
               && table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
              // popup.show(table,me.getX(),me.getY());
              if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                   JTable source = (JTable) me.getSource();
                   int row = source.rowAtPoint(me.getPoint());
                   int column = source.columnAtPoint(me.getPoint());

                   if (!source.isRowSelected(row))
                      source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                   popup.show(table, me.getX(), me.getY());

              }
            }
         }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Credit Check")) {
            System.out.println("you have clicked creditCheckpopup");
            selRows = table.getSelectedRows();
            if (selRows.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < selRows.length; i++) {
                  // get Table data
                    for (int j = 1; j < (table.getColumnCount()) - 1; j++) {
                        rowValueList.add(model.getValueAt(selRows[i], j));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Selection : " + rowValueList);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("you have clicked something idiot");
            }

            int result = new COpxDeal(rowValueList).CheckCredit();
            if (result == 1)
                rowValueList.add("pass");
            else
                rowValueList.add("fail");
            String aValue = (String) rowValueList.get(14);
            for (int i = 0; i < selRows.length; i++) {
                model.setValueAt(aValue, selRows[i], 15);
            }

     // inserted comment (Kleopatra): where are we? that's outside of the TablePopup?
     // okay, nothing like copying the code into an IDE and let that do the formatting, silly me ;-)
     // this is indeed _inside_ the popup, that is the table is recreated
            table = new JTable(model) {
                public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                        int row, int column) {
                    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;

                    // if (!isRowSelected(row)){
                    // c.setBackground(getBackground());
                    // System.out.println(isRowSelected(row));
                    // }
                    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    String strTestValue = "fail";
                    String strTblValue = (String) getModel().getValueAt(
                            modelRow, 15);
                    System.out.println("result :" + strTblValue);
                    if (strTblValue == null || strTblValue.equals(""))
                        System.out.println("there is nothing in strTblValue");
                    else if (strTestValue.equals(strTblValue)) {
                        jc.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    } else {
                        jc.setBackground(Color.green);
                    }

                    return c;
                }
            };

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: editing is whacky somehow - does the editor forget/reset stuff? The code looked perfectly okay in the preview (after a complete copy from my IDE), now lost the first part again ...

Comment: sorry guys, that was my first post..

Answer (score 2):

after some formatting (believe me, it's important for code to be readable ;-) seems like you instantiate a new table inside your popupMenu and only that table has the custom renderer. Which you can do, but doesn't have any effect on the your real table.

Move the prepareRenderer into your real table (the one you pass into the popup as parameter) and you should see the coloring. Beware: due to a bug in DefaultTableCellRenderer, you have to set the color always, that is

```
 if (nothingToDo) {
     setBackground(normal)
 } else if ... {
     setBackground(one)
 } else {
     setBackground(other)
 }
```

Edit: trying to explain the changes in code structure, pseudo-code snippets

Current state, that's what you are doing:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.addMouseListener(new TablePopupListener(table));
     // keep listener-local reference to table
    JTable table = table;
    ....
    // in the listener guts, the reference is replaced
    table = new JTable() {
         @Override
         Component prepareRenderer(... 
    }
```

Change to, that's what you should do:

```
 JTable table = new JTable() {
      @Override
      Component prepareRenderer(...
 };
 table.addMouseListener(new TablePopupListener(table));
     // keep listener-local reference to table
     JTable table = table;
     // don't replace ever, it's for reading only
```

edit 2: 
- changed the pseudo-code to actually register the listener)
- the code indented below the addMouseListener is mean as an outline of the code *inside* the TablePopupListener

Comment: what you told me makes perfect sense. But, how to call a prepared renderer without writing an inner class in Jtable. Can you show share me some sample link or some structure.

Comment: below is how I am calling my pop up ...... jTable.addMouseListener(new TablePopupListener(jTable));which is in a different java file called FileChooser.java.................... so the call goes to TablePopupListener class.The code for the  TablePopupListener class is given in the first post.

Comment: Without calling table = new JTable(model){//prepareRenderer logic} I couldn't call prepareRenderer. I have written this logic in actionPerformed () method of TablePopupListener class.