# Change row color in Swing JTable after sorting rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

We are using a `JTable` which displays data along with Status (`New`, `Processed`, `Closed`). Each status row has a different color which is achieved by overloading `prepareRenderer()` of `JTable`.

Now we need to sort that table and we are using `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);` to achieve that. The rows get sorted properly, but the color of rows remains the same. We need to reapply the color to all the rows after this operation based on the status column.

I was wondering what could be the best way to achieve that. There are several ways I can think of:

1. Repaint/Revalidate the table. But simply doing this would not work I think.
2. Capture `mouseClicked` event and identify whether column header was clicked then call `prepareRenderer()` manually and then call repaint/revalidate
3. Then I read one of the questions here wherein one of the answers was mentioned not to call repaint/revalidate directly, rather change the underlying data model and it will automatically call the above methods.

I don't know how to go about it. Can anyone please provide an insight into what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: sounds like you are missing a convertRowIndexToModel somewhere (assuming the state is held somewhere else)

Comment: Thats a good pointer kleopatra...I am looking into that direction and that could eventually lead to a solution. Thanks and I'll comment all updates here :)

Comment: I read the documentation about TableRowSorter. It says "JTable's row-based methods and JTable's selection model refer to the view and not the underlying model. Therefore, it is necessary to convert between the two. For example, to get the selection in terms of myModel you need to convert the indices".

And it provides a code utilizing convertRowIndexToModel(). That means my general strategy should be associate MouseListener with JTableHeader and upon mouseClicked() call convertRowIndexToModel for every row and then call repaint()/revalidate() on table. Is this approach correct???

Comment: no, far too complicated - everything's should be handled automatically. Time to show some code, the ominous sscce :-)

Comment: Love you Jeanette and my boss too!!! But still the problem is not completely resolved!!! I'll post detailed solution when I deal with it entirely :)

Comment: This is the best example of how to view problem with a different perspective. Don't consider me a philosopher after reading this :D.  
---  
The problem was after sorting the table "visually" i was unable to retain row colors defined based on some status as well as Action button which was enabled/disable based on status.

I correctly perceived it as an issue related to change in view not reflected in model with the help of kleopatra. Now I wanted to sort the model at the same time so that the values are fetched correctly while applying row color, displaying button as renderer......

Comment: and enable/disable button.  
Now my boss came in the picture and told me rather to convert the rows from view to rows in model whereever I was fetching the rows. So I updated prepareRenderer (used for applying colors to rows), getTableCellEditorComponent (to render command button in a cell) and getCellEditorValue (to retrieve actual values in table row). Now everything is working as desired.  
Still the question is which approach is better:  
 1. Sort model after sorting view OR  
 2. Call convertRowIndexToModel() everytime and everywhere you are fetching some values  

Thanks Jeanette

Comment: there is already a similar post on stackoverflow: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878908/jtable-row-color-change-based-on-a-column-value-on-pop-up-click

Answer (score 8):

For change cell color in `JTable` with `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` I used method **table.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(row)**  in my `TableCellRenderer`

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import java.awt.*;

public class OwnTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public OwnTableCellRenderer() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                                                   Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected,
                                                   boolean hasFocus, 
                                                   int row, 
                                                   int column) {

        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.black);

        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        int modelRow = table.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        int columnStatusPosition = 5;
        String statusColumnValue = (String) model.getValueAt(modelRow, columnStatusPosition);

        if (statusColumnValue.equals("ACTIVE")) {
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(Color.green);
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
        }

        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "");
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new OwnTableCellRenderer());
```